# Atom doesnt run cpp file with String

Tags: c++, string, atom-editor

I want to run my cpp file using string, but when I executed, nothing happened.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string x = "hello";
  cout << x;

  return 0;
}
```

When running, it only shows:

```
Press Any Key To Continue...
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo "Press Any Key To Continue..." sorry for that.

Comment: Perhaps it's clearing the screen after execution? You could add a line to pause the program before it ends. `std::cin.get();` before `return` could help.

Comment: `cout << x << endl;` just in case? (endl adds a newline but also flushes the stream)

Comment: What compiler do you use? If it is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile your C++ file `mikael.cc` using the `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g mikael.c -o mikael` command

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, it runs and just shows this. I can't type anything when I use cin as well. I tried this but doesn't work.

Comment: If you compile and run the program from the command line like @BasileStarynkevitch suggested, any difference?

Comment: @Borgleader It doesn't work too, even though I type another message like "cout << "hi" << endl;" my cmd still showing nothing. But when I delete "string x = "hello" my file work well.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, nothing happens too.

Comment: When you compile your program (on the command line), do you get any messages? Can you copy/paste the complete command line you type to compile - and also, how are you executing the program after it's been compiled?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, I tried and nothing happens. https://prnt.sc/10y6u4c <- Print

Comment: @Mikael You must start the program too. Give the command  `./mikael` and it should run.

Comment: No, your compilation command has been successful. You can now read the documentation of GDB and use it appropriately. You may want to use [std::endl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) *after having read its documentation*

Comment: @TedLyngmo Like this? `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g exercise2.cpp -o ./mikae`

Comment: You should understand that [atom](https://atom.io/) is - like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor). The compiler is GCC. The debugger is GDB. Some editors are able to run compilers and debuggers. Neither atom nor emacs are able to run your C++ code.

Comment: @Mikael That command compiles the your code into a program. It does not run the program. Once the code has been compiled, you run it by just typing `./mikael`

Comment: Alright, so thanks!

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I guess you mean `./mikael` -with a dot- not just `/mikael`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch :-) Indeed.